# Google script HTML Datalist displays after entry and backspace

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have two input fields in a sidebar form on google sheets. The Datalist for both inputs are populated from a spreadsheet. The first one shows the options immediately after focus on the input field. The second Datalist is created based on input from the first field. When I dump the information for the second Datalist via alert, it is available.

However, the available options do not show up immediately after focus on the second input field. I can get it to display after hitting space bar and backspace. I have tried some changes with 'onblur' and 'onchange' while loading the data for the second list and nothing changed. Here is the code and form information from the HTML file. I would appreciate any suggestions.

HTML form fields:

```
<input list="food" class="myStyle" id="foodItems" onblur="loadMeasures(this);" > // replaced this line with the line below
<input list="food" class="myStyle" id="foodItems" 
      onblur="resetMeasuresList();loadMeasures(this);" >
      <datalist id="food" placeholder=" food entry"  ></datalist>
      </input><br> 
      <input list="measureList" class="myStyle" id="measure" >
      <datalist id="measureList" > </datalist>
      </input><br>
```

script:

```
function loadFoods(selectObject) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) { 
        var foodSelect = document.getElementById("food");
        ar.forEach(function(item) {
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = item[0];
          foodSelect.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getList()
    }

    function loadMeasures(selectObject) {
      var food = selectObject.value;
      removeOptions(document.getElementById('measureList')); //moved this line to a standalone function 'resetMeasuresList'

      if ( food == "pre fix") {
        google.script.run.preFixView();
      }
      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
        measureSelect = document.getElementById("measureList");
        ar.forEach(function(item) {
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = item[0];
          measureSelect.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getTypeList(food)
    }
```

function used to clear options list

```
function removeOptions(selectElement) {
   var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
   for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
      selectElement.children[i].remove();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please share a sample sheet. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to clear the options list prior to populating it. This was somehow creating a possible blank entry? requiring the space-delete sequence to get to the rest of the options list. I am not sure. In any events moved the code 'removeOptions(document.getElementById('measureList'));' to a separate function. I have modified the original question with the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GS functions that you call via `google.script.run` run asynchronously unless you call them one after another as follows:

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
  //do something
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
    //do something
    google.script.run.function3()
  }).function2()
}).function1()
```

However I suggest you to call first all static data (foods, measuere lists) from sheet once and then manipulate them with client side functions, without needing to call them repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion of reading in everything first time and then selecting from a client side function. However, even with this code, I am able to verify via an alert message that the information for the second table is already available.  It just did not want to show up until I hit the space and delete key.

Comment: @sk65plus If I see your server side codes as well maybe I can help you more.

Comment: If you are writing to a spreadsheet and reading immediately from another function you may find it valuable to utilize SpreadsheetApp.flush() between the two.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this quickly. I was able to resolve part of this by moving the removeOptions(document.getElementById('measureList')); . out of the way. I will edit the original question to display the change I made. The remove prior options list was somehow causing something to be left in the options list ? I am not sure.